# Hive How to disable Semantic check 'Schema of both sides of union should match'

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, hdp

#### Two same Hive 2.1

I have two hadoop cluster:

1. HDP 2.x with Hive 2.1.0 r6177e19d5af719688732bbffc2a7953295e62b0a (select version();)
2. CDH 6.x with Hive 2.1.1-cdh6.3.2 rb3393cf499504df1d2a12d34b4285e5d0c02be11 (select version();)

#### The same SQL

I run below SQL

```sql
set hive.execution.engine=spark;

with t1 as (
    select 1 as id, 11 as code
)
, t2 as (
    select 2 as id, '22' as code
)
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2;
```

#### HDP works

In the HDP cluster, this SQL executable.
[image: HDP Hive]

#### But CDH failed

But in the CDH cluster, this SQL throws:

> [42000][40000] Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 9:14 Schema of both sides of union should match: Column code is of type int on first table and type string on second table. Error encountered near token 't2'

[image: CDH Hive]

#### What's the difference? How to fix?

So what's the difference between these two Hive?

We have a lot of SQL like this and we cannot afford the cost to change them all using `cast(xxx as string)`. How to make the CDH Hive work like HDP?

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Either don't use apostrophes or use apostrophes on both. My guess is you're going to have to fix one way or another.

Comment: Reiew https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14251

Comment: "We have a lot of SQL like this" why? It's basic SQL semantics that you need to have the same type in both parts of the union.

Comment: @Charlieface You're right, I think we have to change those SQL once and for all eventually.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Hive issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14251, this is a BUG, so there's no setting for it.

There are two solutions:

1. Adjust your SQLs. (Recommended)
2. Reverse this patch for your cluster. (A lot of effort)